# How to redirect and remove index.php in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using below htaccess to remove index.php from my url in Codeigniter.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The problem is that user can still use below code to access the method :

```
http://example.com/index.php/controller/method
```

How can I **redirect** them to url without index.php or send them to an **error** page if they add index.php ?

Comment: The duplicate marking of this question is incorrect. This is a follow-on case where the questioner wants to both acheive the removal of the index.php and also redirect any existing links/bookmarks to the new URL. The related question doesn't tell you how to do that second part - which is what the questioner is clearly asking about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

first rule redirects user non index.php site perminantly then it comes to your second rule and bingo.

Comment: Changed 301 to 302 to conserve SEO link matches within search engines. I'll delete my answer, yours has the redirect.

Comment: Now I'm getting error that this page has a redirect loop

Comment: @rcpayan: change your last rule to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`. Apache treats index.php/$1 as a redirect.

Comment: @user181892: this last comment should fix the loop :-)

Comment: @rcpayan thank you for your answer, unfortunately I can't vote up cuz I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Sebastian thx for correction, you got a point. And u dont need to vote up but you can accept it as an answer

Comment: @SébastienRenauld thank you. I never would have figured that out. Can you provide a reference for why Apache treats it so, and how the `?` is interpreted to alter that? (I can't see anything under http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule to explain it!)